# NullPointerException - But why?

Tags: java

In the following part:

```
Statusframe statusframe = new Statusframe();
long sendetBytes = 0;
int percent = 0;

while((i = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    outF.write(buffer, 0, i);
    outF.flush();
    l += i;
    if(l==(int)sendetBytes)
        break;


    sendetBytes += 1048576;
    percent = (int) (sendetBytes / filelength);
    statsuframe.getPbStatus().setValue(percent);


}

outF.close();

statusframe.getFrStatusframe().dispose();
```

I get a NullPointerException of "statusfenster" in the line

```
statusframe.getPbStatus().setValue(percent);
```

and later i would get it too in

```
statusframe.getFrStatusframe().dispose();
```

But i don't understand why? I created already a object for "statusframe" in the first line...Also i created in Statusframe.java a object for pbStatus.

Additional information: This code here is running in a seperate thread.

**EDIT:**

@Zaheer Ahmed:

This mistake is but i written this code not in english and translate it here manually.

The mistake was in the Statusframe.java constructor. The code for creating pbStatus and all this stuff was not in the constructor, it was in a seperate method and i forgot it to call it in the constructor....

Sorry for this mistake, but thanks for your help!!!

Comment: most likely `statsuframe.getPbStatus()` returns `null`.

Comment: `getPbStatus()` and `getFrStatusframe()` return `null`.

Comment: Propably `statsuframe.getPbStatus()`returns null.

Comment: It might possible you are getting an exception at this line `percent = (int) (sendetBytes / filelength);` I have doubt on 'filelength' value.

Comment: In any case, you forgot to multiply by 100 - so this percent will always be either 0 or 1.

Comment: its statusframe not statsuframe define in variable above.

Comment: Hello, you can write your own answer  and accept it

Answer (score 0):

If this line

```
statusframe.getPbStatus().setValue(percent);
```

Throws an NPE, you should ensure **both**  that

1. `statusframe` is not null, and
2. The object returned from `statusframe.getPbStatus()` is not null.

Given your code, it's likely that #2 is the source of your issue.

Method chaining like that is handy, but it may cause ambiguity as it seems to have in your case.

Feel free to separate it into something like:

```
SOME_PB_STATUS_OBJECT status = statusframe.getPbStatus();
status.setValue(percent);
```

Of course, *explicitly* checking for a null value in the case where it could be returned is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
statusframe.getPbStatus()
```

is probably returning null

Comment: @user3146246 : post the constructor code. did you check whether the object is in scope(i.e whether it is globally declared)?

Answer (score 0):

Dont exactly know your implementation here, put null check on `statsuframe.getPbStatus()` will solve:

```
if(statusframe!=null && statusframe.getPbStatus()!= null)
   statusframe.getPbStatus().setValue(percent);
```

if you getPbStatus() change on calling it on twice then you may try:

```
if(statusframe!=null){
   var status = statsuframe.getPbStatus();
   if(status!=null){
      status.setValue(percent);
   }
}
```

## Error in your code:

you defined: `statusframe` here:

```
Statusframe statusframe = new Statusframe();
```

but u accessing wrong variable `statsuframe`:

```
statsuframe.getPbStatus().setValue(percent);
```

Comment: Calling `getPbStatus()` twice may have unintended side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe either you are using a wrong variable name `statsuframe` in your code or you have misprinted something in question.

If it is not a mistake while pasting contents to SO then probably you should use,

```
statusframe .getPbStatus().setValue(percent);
```

instead as mentioned in question as

```
 statsuframe.getPbStatus().setValue(percent);
```